# Android Phonegap Scroll is Very Choppy

Tags: javascript, android, css, cordova, scroll

I'm building a very basic webapp that displays ferry schedules.

I'm using phonegap to port it to a "native" app on Android and I'm have a bit of trouble with the scrolling.

It works perfectly in Chrome on the device, as well as on the android browser. I've tested on several devices and they all work great in browser. As soon as I put the project into Phonegap however the scroll becomes very "choppy" and skips and sticks. I've added a video link to show you the behaviour:

http://youtu.be/D18s9kgnD7g

I'll give you a brief explanation of how it works:

We're using translate3d CSS methods for transitions when we switch content in view so that we avoid using page transitions. Because of this we're not scrolling the actual page we're scrolling individual content divs so that we avoid weird scrolling bugs when switching between content views. Basically we have three "content views" on one page that switch out when we want to switch views.

Here's a link to the app:

http://ferriesapp.ca/app/

**Things I've tried**

We're using "overscroll: scroll;" one these content divs, which I know had some incompatibilty with Android pre 2.3 but should be good now.

We've tried a few big libraries, like iScroll and Scrollable, and things like that to no avail.

I've tried preventing default actions for touchmove.

We've coded correct touch events using Zepto's touch module.

I've tested on devices from the Nexus one (4.0.4) to the Nexus 7 (4.3) and it's the same story on all those devices.

**Any help would be STRONGLY appreciated**

I've been struggling with this for a while now and I can't seem to find anything on the internet that hits on this "choppy" scrolling bug.

EDIT: Here's a logcat from installation to when the scrolling bug happens:
http://pastebin.com/Aa7mDeAX

Comment: Android Webview doesn't support the full feature set of the Chrome browser. Check/post your logcat to see if any helpful messages appear.

Comment: @MorrisonChang here's the unfiltered LogCat from installation right to when the scrolling bug happens... I'm still new to Android development so I don't really know what any of this means: http://pastebin.com/Aa7mDeAX

Comment: I didn't see anything in your log, perhaps someone else does. You might want to try turning off hardware acceleration in your app to see how it affects the app. See Google IO session on Android WebView: https://developers.google.com/events/io/2012/sessions/gooio2012/122/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got a pretty nasty style sheet there.  First, you do not want any box shaddow because mobile does not like that.  Then, since you have a lot of blank spaces, you want to help touch to work better with those blanks with user-select: html.

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-user-select:html;
    -khtml-user-select:html;
    -moz-user-select:html;
    -ms-user-select:html;
    user-select:html;
}
```

That should help with your scrolling, but you still have tons of thing to clean up with that CSS.  Another issue is that you don't even have cordova loaded correctly, but that probably doesn't really matter for scrolling.

Actually, what is zepto_002.js?  That seem to be the one that is causing the main scrolling issue.

Comment: Hey, I don't see where you see zepto_002.js We aren't linking that anywhere in the code and it's not in our resources? Where did you see that?

Comment: Sorry, I downloaded the code so I can try it on the actual device since that's the only way to use it.  zepto_002.js is probably  your zepto.min.js.  When I remove that, scrolling works fine.  And since it may not be zepto, it might be something with your script that use zepto.

Comment: Hey It was the Zepto touch module that was causing issues! I've deleted that and now I'm all good! Thanks!

Comment: I have a curiosity regarding the value used for the `user-select` property. Why `html`? I searched for it and doesn't exist( https://caniuse.com/#search=user-select%3A%20html )

Answer (score 0):

As a fellow google play developer, having "three "content views" on one page that switch out when we want to switch views" is not a good idea. my only input though if you want to go this path would be to check this out http://pocketnow.com/2012/05/25/what-is-force-gpu-rendering-in-ice-cream-sandwich

Comment: Hey Sam, Thanks for the input, I knew about the force gpu rendering before posting this and even forcing that doesn't seem to do a thing. As for the 3 content views, it's not ajax loading them or anything, it's just "moving them" we did this to avoid having to use page loads.